# Get only listitems from sharepoint 2013 with odata api

Tags: rest, odata, sharepoint-2013

How I can get only listitems form the sharepoint search over the odata rest api?

```
MYURL/_api/search/query?querytext=' Path:\"MYDOCUMENTLIBPATH\" '&selectproperties='ListItemID,TitleDEOWSTEXT, TitleITOWSTEXT, AreaTitleDEOWSTXT, AreaTitleITOWSTXT, Language1OWSCHCS'&sortlist=''&rowlimit=25&startrow=0
```

At the moment I am using the query above but it returns me even the list that contains the document of my search. How I can avoid this?

Comment: i have found this workaround maybe there is a better solution:
DocumentLink:MYURL/MYDOCUMENTLIBNAME/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using ContentClass. "STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary" for Document Library Items and "STS_ListItem" for Custom ListItems.

For Example:

MYURL/_api/search/query?querytext='Path:"MYDOCUMENTLIBPATH" AND ContentClass="STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary"'&selectproperties='ListItemID,TitleDEOWSTEXT, TitleITOWSTEXT, AreaTitleDEOWSTXT, AreaTitleITOWSTXT, Language1OWSCHCS'&sortlist=''&rowlimit=25&startrow=0